# Can Azure Devops pipelines update Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-app-configuration

Had a quick google, and there appears to be nothing out there.

Can an Azure Pipeline update Azure App Configuration? Or would it make sense to be builds and deployment/run-time config away from each other

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can rickvdbosch's answer helps to resolve your issue? If this issue persists to block you, feel free to let us know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure App Configuration Push task works pretty well now :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest solution to get this working is by using Azure CLI which you can integrate into your pipelines using the [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).

To update, use the [az appconfig kv set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/appconfig/appconfig/kv?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-appconfig-az-appconfig-kv-set) command.

> Set a key using an App Configuration name and label
>   `az appconfig kv set -n {name} --key {key1} --label {label} --value {value1} --content-type {text} --tags {tag1,tag2}`

Answer (score 2):

> Can an Azure Pipeline update Azure App Configuration?

Apart from the `az appconfig kv set` in **rickvdbosch's** answer, you can also consider using [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview) which can also be used to manage app settings. See similar hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52275577/10910450).

You can use `Override template parameters` option in [Azure Resource Group Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops) to update the app configurations in build/release pipeline.

[image]